# Show and hide loading image while loading PHP data

Tags: php, jquery

I am using jQuery and PHP to save content that the user inputs in a database. While the PHP is doing its thing I want to show a loading GIF image just to show that it is saving their data. I realize that it probably does take that long for it to run the code so i want to be able to show the image for at least 1 second if it takes less time than that

Comment: I want to eat a pack of Gushers.  Have you tried anything?

Comment: JQuery beforeSend and success are your friends : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: could you please expand on beforeSend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, I'm using the following script as a live search form in a database.
The user types some letters and the script search if a student with that name exists in the database:

### file index.php

```
<head>
//call to jquery.js
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready( function() {
 $('#q').keyup( function(){
  $field = $(this);
  $('#results').html('');
  $('#ajax-loader_e').remove();

  if( $field.val().length > 1 )
  {
    var str='q='+$(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      type : 'GET',
      url : 'ajax_search.php' ,
      data : str ,
      beforeSend : function() {
       $field.after('<img src="../img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loader" id="ajax-loader_e" />');
      },
      success : function(data){
        $('#ajax-loader_e').remove();
        $('#results').html(data);
      }
    });//end ajax
  }//end if     
 });//end keyup
});//end ready
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form class="quick_search">
  <input type="text" value="Name" id="q" name="q" onfocus="if(!this._haschanged){this.value=''};this._haschanged=true;">
</form>
<div id="results_e"></div>
```

### file ajax_search.php

```
if(isset($_GET['q'])){
  $nom='%'.safe($_GET['q']).'%';
  $req=$connexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM students WHERE name LIKE :name LIMIT 0,10 ");
  $req->execute(array('name'=>$name));
  echo "<ul>";
  while($row=$req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    if(empty($row)){
      echo "<h4 class='alert_error'>No one with that name!</h4>";
    }
    else{
      echo "<li><strong><a href='?id=".$row['id']."'>".clean($row['nom']).' '.clean($row['prenom'])."</a></strong></li>";
    }
  }
  echo "</ul>";
}
```

You can use that script to save a form via ajax and display a loader gif while waiting.
The important parts are:

- remove the loader in the beginning
- in beforeSend, display the loader
- remove the loader in success

Comment: ahh ok so just a beforeSend and success method to show and hide the image thank you so much!